# PPAPI plugin run EXE on windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ppapi

I have a npapi plugin that run an exe on the client machine, now npapi is deprecated on chrome, so I'm trying to port my plugin to PPAPI.

Can I run an EXE from the PPAPI plugin?

Note: I only need this to run in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  See this post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/1quAy0Y_xa4

This type of behavior is one of the major reasons npapi was deprecated, this capability is a huge security issue.  If you don't need the exe to run silently, there are some methods there, however.